# Why does not File.deleteOnExit work with directory?

Tags: java

Am I using `deleteOnExit` in a wrong way?

I create a directory and then run:

`new File("my_dir_path").deleteOnExit();`

But the directory is never removed after JVM terminates without error, despite that JDK doc says `Requests that the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname be deleted when the virtual machine terminates.`

Comment: is that my_dir_path non-empty?

Comment: thank you, I guess it is the case.

Comment: To effectively `deleteOnExit` a directory try a [`shutdown hook`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24001535/5432315)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The directory must be empty in order to delete it.