# File.deleteOnExit() For Non-Empty Folders?

Tags: java, file, file-io, io

I noticed in : [Why does not File.deleteOnExit work with directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038065/why-does-not-file-deleteonexit-work-with-directory) that I couldn't delete a non empty folder with `File.deleteOnExit()`. Is there any way to do a similar operation? Or should I try to register all files below it and then the parent directory using `file.deleteOnExit()`? Or should I try * shudders * a finalizer?

Comment: None of the above. Write a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)).

Comment: Never use deleteOnExit() in a long-running server. It will cause a memory leak.